# How can I localize AspNetCore built in messages in French?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Using the AspNetCore 1.1 preview 1 bits all examples I can found on the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html) demonstration how to localize my own resouces, I would like to localize the built in messages, for instance validation messages.

My application is only intented to be used by French people so my default culture is fr-FR.

How can I localize all the built in resources into French ?

Comment: The client's browser should request in french using the `Accept-Language` http header. However, you can setup the default locale using a request filter and seting the locale on the current thread (something like `Thread.Current.CurrentLocale = [...]`, I can't remember exactly).

Comment: What do you mean with "built in messages"?

Comment: Those returned by the framework, like standard validation messages from validation attributes, authentifcation messages from identity results, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 1.1 preview 1, there is no API to convert *all* framework messages into a different language.

For data annotation validation, you can customize error messages in code. Given that you are just looking to support French, you may find it easiest to override the `ValidationAttribute.ErrorMessage` property.

Example:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "(Translation for 'this email is invalid' here)")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

You could also use the `ValidationAttribute.ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ValidationAttribute.ErrorMessageResourceType` properties. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute for more details

If you want even more low-level control, you would need to override framework localization. API such `IStringLocalizer` exist. The [documentation you linked to](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html) introduces some of those extensibility points. (Checkout https://aspnetsource.azurewebsites.net if you want to inspect how framework code calls these APIs.)

Comment: The problem with that approach is that I have to know every strings to localize, since it's not to hard for validation messages it becomes nightmare when you have to deal with identity results messages. Thanks for the answer though.